# Counting the pairs that come together with a high value in a dataset

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I have a set of data with column headings A, B, C, D, E ... K. and in the cells, there are values between 0-6. I am looking for a way to count and list the  pairs or triples that have high values (4,5,6).

For example, if A and B columns have 5 and 6 in the same row respectively, then it should be counted in the calculation of the occurrences. If it is 1 and 6, 1 and 5, etc, then it should be skipped. It should be only counted if both (can be more than 2 columns) have high values on the same row.

Basically, I want to count and list the columns if they have high values in the same row. I am open for all types of solutions. I'd really appreciate if someone guide me how to do this. thanks.

Example Output:

```
Pairs   Number of Occurrences (can be (5,6), (4,6),(5,5), (4,5), (6,6))         
AB          10          
BC          20          
CE          30
```

Here is a picture of my data.
This is just a part of my actual data. Not the complete list. I am sorry, I said values between 0 and 6. I deleted 0s, and they are all blank now.

[image]

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M
3   3   2   4   2   4   5   4   2   2   4   3   3
2   4   3   3   3   3   6   4   2   3   3   2   4
3   3   2   4   2   4   3   3   3   3   3   3   3
3   3   4   2   4   2   4   3   3   5   1   3   3
2   4   4   2   4   2   3   6       4   2   2   4
2   4   2   4   2   4   3   3   3   3   3   2   4
3   3   2   4   2   4   3   3   3   3   3   3   3
5   1   2   4   2   4   3   3   3   3   3   5   1
2   4   1   5   1   5   3   4   2   3   3   2   4
3   3   2   4   2   4   3   3   3   3   3   3   3
5   1   2   4   2   4   2   3   3   3   3   5   1
3   3   2   4   2   4   3   4   2   4   2   3   3
4   2   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   4   2   4   2
3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   6   0   3   3
2   4   3   3   3   3   3   4   2   5   1   2   4
4   2   2   4   2   4   3   1   5   3   3   4   2
2   4   4   2   4   2   4   3   3   3   3   2   4
3   3   2   4   2   4   3   2   4   4   2   3   3
3   3   4   2   4   2   4   3   3   3   3   3   3
4   2   2   4   2   4   3   3   3   3   3   4   2
2   4   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   4   2   2   4
2   4   2   4   2   4   2   2   4   4   2   2   4
4   2   3   3   3   3   5   4   2   1   5   4   2
3   3   3   3   3   3   3   4   2   3   3   3   3
1   5   2   4   2   4   3   4   2   2   4   1   5
5   1   4   2   4   2   6   1   5   3   3   5   1
4   2   1   5   1   5   3   3   3   2   4   4   2
1   5   2   4   2   4   1   3   3   3   3   1   5
2   4   4   2   4   2   1   2   4   2   4   2   4
4   2   5   1   5   1   2   4   2   3   3   4   2
4   2   1   5   1   5   4   1   5   4   2   4   2
2   4   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   6   0   2   4
4   2   2   4   2   4   3   3   3   3   3   4   2
```

Comment: *for example, if A and columns have 5 and 6 in the same row respectively, then it should be counted in the calculation of the occurrences.* What? Not sure what you're asking. Can you give example outputs?

Comment: I am sorry about the explanation. I updated my post, and added an example output. It's just an exemplary table. It can be anyway you want as long as it gives the results.

Comment: So, for each pair of columns, you want to know how many pairs there are of (4,5), (4,6), or (5,6)?

Comment: yes. that is what I need.

Comment: do the pair cells have to be in the same row? I don't see any in AB. To me it sounds a bit like `=COUNTIFS(A1:A33, ">3", B1:B33, ">3")`

Comment: @Slai As I interpret the question, that wouldn't work because the OP wants to exclude for example the pair (6,6) which your formula would include.

Comment: Slai, AB is an example. I didn't write the examples looking at the table. my mistake sorry.. they should be in the same row.

Comment: I need high value pairs between 4-6. so (6,6) is included.I Updated my post :) again..

Comment: then it seems you can count them all at once with something like `=COUNTIFS($A2:M99, ">3", $B2:N99, ">3")`

Comment: Yes. but I won't know which pair have high values.. ab, cd, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made two helper columns that list the pairs of columns, then used this formula to calculate the pairs of `(4,5)`, `(4,6)`, and `(5,6)`.

```
= SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(INDEX($A:$M,0,MATCH(O2,$A$1:$M$1,0)),{4,4,5,5,6,6},
                      INDEX($A:$M,0,MATCH(P2,$A$1:$M$1,0)),{5,6,6,4,4,5}))
```

**EDIT** *Based on your most recent comment, formula is updated to this:*

```
= COUNTIFS(INDEX($A:$M,0,MATCH(O2,$A$1:$M$1,0)),">3",
           INDEX($A:$M,0,MATCH(P2,$A$1:$M$1,0)),">3"))
```

See example below, I didn't do it for every single of columns, but gave it a good start:

Note your original data is to the left in my spreadsheet, I didn't show it here just to save space.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, @ImaginaryHuman072889. It works nice. You saved my day :)

Answer (score 2):

here goes a VBA solution exploiting Dictionary (which requires to add reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` library):

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim col As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    Dim pairDict As Scripting.Dictionary

    Set pairDict = New Scripting.Dictionary

    With Worksheets("rates")
        With .Range("a1").CurrentRegion
            For Each col In .Columns.Resize(, .Columns.Count - 1) 'loop through referenced range columns except the last one
                .AutoFilter Field:=col.Column, Criteria1:=">4" 'filter reference range on current column with values > 4
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, col) > 1 Then ' if any filtered cells except header
                    For Each cell In Intersect(.Offset(, col.Column).Resize(, .Columns.Count - col.Column), .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow) 'loop through each row of filtered cells from one column right of current one to the last one
                        If cell.Value > 4 Then pairDict(.Cells(1, col.Column).Value & .Cells(1, cell.Column).Value) = pairDict(.Cells(1, col.Column).Value & .Cells(1, cell.Column).Value) + 1 ' if current cell value is >4 then update dictionary with key=combination of columns pair first row content and value=value+1
                    Next
                End If
                .AutoFilter 'remove current filter
            Next
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False 'remove filters headers
    End With

    If pairDict.Count > 0 Then ' if any pair found
        Dim key As Variant
        For Each key In pairDict.Keys 'loop through each dictionary key
            Debug.Print key, pairDict(key) 'print the key (i.e. the pair of matching columns first row content) and the value ( i.e. the number of occurrences found)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, I did what you said, but it didn't give any results. I added reference to MS scripting dictionary, changed the name of the sheet to "rates". but it didn't give any results. I have excel 2007. there is some processing going on, but at the end I see the table as it is.

Comment: the results are being printed in the Immediate Window by the statement `Debug.Print`. So keep the VBA IDE open to see them

Comment: Thanks a lot, I saw it now. I didn't know that. :)

Comment: you are welcome. if you want them to be printed in the sheet it's a matter of statements like: `Range(...).Resize(pairDict.count,1).Value = Application.Transpose(pairDict.Keys)` nad `Range(...).Resize(pairDict.count+1,1).Value = Application.Transpose(pairDict.Items)`

Comment: you're welcome again. are you going to use this solution?